# Reference net7.0-windows from a net7.0 project not possible?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a net7.0-windows (wpf) project. I added a unit test project net7.0.

I am allowed to reference net7.0 project from the net7.0-windows project.

I am *not* allowed to reference net7.0-windows project from my net7.0 test project. Why not?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Because a .NET 7 project is platform agnostic. If it could reference a .NET 7 Windows project it would only be guaranteed to work on Windows.

Comment: Consider the following: what if you tried to use that test project on Linux. What then?

Comment: right, that makes perfect sense.... my bad